# How can i redirect after successful submit of form using react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

action.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { EVENT_ADD_FAIL, EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS } from '../constraints/eventConstraint';

const addEvent = (event) => async (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, payload: event });
 try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/event`, event);
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS, payload:data });
 }
 catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_FAIL, payload:error.message });
 };
};


export { addEvent };
```

constraint.js

```
export const EVENT_ADD_REQUEST = 'EVENT_ADD_REQUEST';
export const EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS = 'EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS';
export const EVENT_ADD_FAIL = 'EVENT_ADD_FAIL';
```

reducer.js

```
import {EVENT_ADD_FAIL, EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS } from "../constraints/eventConstraint";

function eventAddReducer(state = {}, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
    case EVENT_ADD_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
    case EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, event: action.payload, success:true };
    case EVENT_ADD_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload, success:false };
    default:
        return state
 };
};

export { eventAddReducer }
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { eventAddReducer } from './reducers/eventReducer';

const initialState = {};
const reducer = combineReducers({
  addEvent: eventAddReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
export default store
```

event.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addEvent } from '../actions/eventAction';

const AddEvent = () => {
 const history = useHistory();
 const [event, setEvent] = useState();
 const addNewEvent = useSelector(state => state.addEvent);
 console.log(addNewEvent)
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const handleChange = e => {
    setEvent({ ...event,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
 };

 const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await dispatch(addEvent(event));
 };

// if(addNewEvent.success === true) {   
//     history.push('/')
// };   ===========>>>>>>>>>>> It works at first but after submission first time next time it automatically redirects to '/' because react-redux holds state

return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit = { submitHandler } >
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" name="description" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="price" name="price" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <Link to='/'> <button type="button" className="btn btn-success"> Back </button> </Link>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success float-right"> Add Event </button>
        </form>
    </>
 )
};

export default AddEvent
```

Everything is working fine but I want after successful submission of the form it needs to redirect to some page. It is simple without react-redux we can simply redirect after submission of form but I am trying to learn redux and don't know much about redux. I tried to use success = true in reducer it works at the first time but as redux holds state when I tried to open the link it automatically redirects to the homepage as success = true is hold by react-redux. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you could use a middleware that looks for a specific key in the dispatched action object, and triggers a route redirect when it finds it.

Comment: can you please elaborate more

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Make sure you reset `success` per action:

```
function eventAddReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
     case EVENT_ADD_REQUEST:
         return { 
           loading: true,
           success: null // <-- Look at this
          };
    /** ... */
  };
};
```

**Second:** Connect `success` store-variable to your component, and check for it in `componentDidupdate` event like:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AddEvent extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {success} = this.props;
    const {succcess: prevSuccess} = prevProps;

    if (success && success !== prevSuccess) {
      /** Redirect here */
    }
  }
  /** .... */
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ addEvent: { success } }) => ({
  success
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AddEvent);
```

**Using Hooks**

```
const AddEvent = ({ success }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      /** Redirect here */
    }
  }, [success]); // <-- This will make sure that the effect only runs when success variable has changed
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ addEvent: { success } }) => ({
  success
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AddEvent);
```

Comment: but i want to use functional component not class component

Comment: It still not working as after success to true it does not hit until we submit form

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem now, and I solved it in two ways

1. The first: to complete your solution at

`event.js` file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addEvent } from '../actions/eventAction';

const AddEvent = () => {
 const history = useHistory();
 const [event, setEvent] = useState();
 const addNewEvent = useSelector(state => state.addEvent);
 console.log(addNewEvent)
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const handleChange = e => {
    setEvent({ ...event,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
 };

 const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await dispatch(addEvent(event));
 };
addNewEvent.success && history.push('/')

return (
    <>
    // after submition success only you will redirect to "/"

    {addNewEvent.success && history.push('/')}
    
        <form onSubmit = { submitHandler } >
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" name="description" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="price" name="price" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <Link to='/'> <button type="button" className="btn btn-success"> Back </button> </Link>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success float-right"> Add Event </button>
        </form>
    </>
 )
};

export default AddEvent
```

we can only access success value from store reducer after return not before, so you can access value every re-render and redirect based on your condition

now in `react-router-dom v6` you can use `useNavigate()` and make changes for below lines

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// rest of imports

const AddEvent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

//rest of code
return (
<>
{addNewEvent.success && navigate('/')}

//rest of code

</>

)
};
export default AddEvent
```

2. The second: you can make condition at `action.js` by sending navigate as an argument on dispatch action and write your condition after dispatch success as below

`event.js` file

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// rest of imports

const AddEvent = () => {
 const navigate = useNavigate();

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   await dispatch(addEvent(event,navigate));
};

//rest of code
return (
<>

//rest of code

</>

)
};
export default AddEvent
```

and at `action.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { EVENT_ADD_FAIL, EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS } from '../constraints/eventConstraint';

const addEvent = (event,navigate) => async (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, payload: event });
 try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/event`, event);
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS, payload:data });
    
    //add your navigation or condition here
    navigate("/");

 }
 catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_FAIL, payload:error.message });
 };
};


export { addEvent };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this not the most ideal solution , but how about creating an action that will reset success and dispatch it inside of an useEffect?

Something like this:

Reducer

```js
import {EVENT_ADD_FAIL, EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS } from "../constraints/eventConstraint";

function eventAddReducer(state = {}, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
    case EVENT_ADD_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
    case EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, event: action.payload, success:true };
    case EVENT_ADD_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload, success:false };
case RESET:
      return {
         ...state, 
         loading: false, 
         success:false
      } // This will reset everything including success
    default:
        return state
 };
};

export { eventAddReducer }
```

and in your event.js file call an action that will dispatch RESET. Make sure you put it inside of an useeffect.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addEvent } from '../actions/eventAction';

const AddEvent = () => {
 const history = useHistory();
 const [event, setEvent] = useState();
 const addNewEvent = useSelector(state => state.addEvent);
 console.log(addNewEvent)
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
React.useEffect(() =>{
myResetAction()

}, [])
 const handleChange = e => {
    setEvent({ ...event,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
 };

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await dispatch(addEvent(event));
 };

// if(addNewEvent.success === true) {   
//     history.push('/')
// };   ===========>>>>>>>>>>> It works at first but after submission first time next time it automatically redirects to '/' because react-redux holds state

return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit = { submitHandler } >
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" name="description" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="price" name="price" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
            <Link to='/'> <button type="button" className="btn btn-success"> Back </button> </Link>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success float-right"> Add Event </button>
        </form>
    </>
 )
)}
```

Doing this will help.